# Platform-independent file paths?

Tags: python, path, cross-platform

How can I use a file inside my app folder in Python?  Platform independent of course...
something similar to this:

```
#!/bin/sh
mypath=${0%/*}
LIBDIR=$mypath/modules
```

Answer (score 124, accepted):

You can use `os.path` and its functions, which take care of OS-specific paths:

```
>>> import os
>>> os.path.join('app', 'subdir', 'dir', 'filename.foo')
'app/subdir/dir/filename.foo'
```

On Windows, it should print out with backslashes.

Comment: It actually prints 'app\\subdir\\dir\\filename.foo' for me.

Comment: @ArditS. That's because you need to escape backslashes in strings. If you add `print`, you'll see that `print(os.path.join("foo", "bar", "baz"))` does indeed print `foo\bar\baz`.

Answer (score 30):

```
import os
os.path.join(os.path.curdir, 'file.name')
```

or

```
import os
os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'file.name')
```

depending upon whether it's a module *(2)* or a single script *(1)*, and whether you're invoking it from the same directory *(1)*, or from a different one *(2)*.

### Edit

Looking at the "attempt" you have in your question, I'd guess that you'd want *(1)*.

Comment: the use of os.path.curdir was super helpful for me when navigating data in my project +1

Answer (score 12):

In Python 3.4+ you can use [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html):

```
from pathlib import Path

libdir = Path(__file__).resolve().with_name('modules')
```

How it works: the `__file__` attribute contains the pathname of the file from which the module was loaded. You use it to initialize a `Path` object , make the path absolute using the [`resolve()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.resolve) method and replace the final path component using the [`with_name()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.PurePath.with_name) method.

Answer (score 5):

`__file__` contains the module's location. Use the functions in `os.path` to extract the directory from it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this CLR-compliant way:

```
import os
AppDomain = type('', (object,), {'__init__': (lambda self: self.CurrentDomain = type('', (object,), {'__init__': (lambda self: self.BaseDirectory = os.path.split(__file__)[0])})())})()
```

Usage:

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory
```

Inspired by `System.AppDomain` in .NET Framework **and** Core.

Do you know how it works? First off, it `import`s `os`. After that, it creates a variable called `AppDomain` which is set into an instance of a type where its constructor sets its own `CurrentDomain` to an instance of a type where its constructor sets its own `BaseDirectory` to the first element in the array returned by `os.path.split` with the value of `__file__` (the module path) as a parameter.