# Platform independent path concatenation using "/" , "\"?

Tags: python, path

In python I have variables `base_dir` and `filename`. I would like to concatenate them to obtain `fullpath`. But under windows I should use `\` and for POSIX `/` .

```
fullpath = "%s/%s" % ( base_dir, filename ) # for Linux
```

How can I make this platform independent?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Platform-independent file paths?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6036129/platform-independent-file-paths)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Platform-independent file paths?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6036129/platform-independent-file-paths)

Comment: See also [this answer on Why use os.path.join over string concatenation?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13944874/1078556)

Answer (score 205, accepted):

You want to use [os.path.join()](http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html?highlight=os.path.join#os.path.join) for this.

The strength of using this rather than string concatenation etc is that it is aware of the various OS specific issues, such as path separators. Examples:

```
import os
```

Under **Windows 7**:

```
base_dir = r'c:\bla\bing'
filename = r'data.txt'

os.path.join(base_dir, filename)
'c:\\bla\\bing\\data.txt'
```

Under **Linux**:

```
base_dir = '/bla/bing'
filename = 'data.txt'

os.path.join(base_dir, filename)
'/bla/bing/data.txt'
```

The [os](http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html) module contains many useful methods for directory, path manipulation and finding out OS specific information, such as the separator used in paths via [os.sep](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html?highlight=os.sep#os.sep)

Answer (score 27):

Use [`os.path.join()`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html#os.path.join):

```
import os
fullpath = os.path.join(base_dir, filename)
```

The [os.path](http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html) module contains all of the methods you should need for platform independent path manipulation, but in case you need to know what the path separator is on the current platform you can use [`os.sep`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.sep).

Comment: it is not *full* path if `base_dir` is a relative path (despite OP uses it)

Comment: Adding an `abspath()` call should make it a full path if there's anything relative in it.

Comment: @Andrew Clark, os.sep returns "\\" on Windows, but it still works even if I use "/". Is there any problem if we just use "/"?

Answer (score 25):

Digging up an old question here, but on Python 3.4+ you can use [pathlib operators](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#operators):

```
from pathlib import Path

# evaluates to ./src/cool-code/coolest-code.py on Mac
concatenated_path = Path("./src") / "cool-code\\coolest-code.py"
```

It's potentially more readable than `os.path.join()` if you are fortunate enough to be running a recent version of Python. But, you also tradeoff compatibility with older versions of Python if you have to run your code in, say, a rigid or legacy environment.

Comment: I am very fond of `pathlib`. However, it is often not installed by default in Python2 installations. If you do not want users to have to go through installing pathlib as well, `os.path.join()` is the simpler way to go.

Comment: The `/` operator is convenient when working with existing objects. When using the constructor directly, you can just pass multiple arguments to construct the path. i.e. `Path("./src", "cool-code", "coolest-code.py")`

Answer (score 12):

```
import os
path = os.path.join("foo", "bar")
path = os.path.join("foo", "bar", "alice", "bob") # More than 2 params allowed.
```

Answer (score 0):

I've made a helper class for this:

```
import os

class u(str):
    """
        Class to deal with urls concat.
    """
    def __init__(self, url):
        self.url = str(url)

    def __add__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, u):
            return u(os.path.join(self.url, other.url))
        else:
            return u(os.path.join(self.url, other))

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.url

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.url
```

The usage is:

```
    a = u("http://some/path")
    b = a + "and/some/another/path" # http://some/path/and/some/another/path
```

Comment: Will this not insert backslashes on Windows?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for this. For anyone else who sees this using fbs or pyinstaller and frozen apps.

I can use the below which works perfect now.

```
target_db = os.path.join(os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(sys.argv[0])), "sqlite_example.db")
```

I was doing this fugliness before which was obviously not ideal.

```
if platform == 'Windows':
    target_db = (os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(sys.argv[0])) + "\\" + "sqlite_example.db")

if platform == 'Linux' or 'MAC':
    target_db = (os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(sys.argv[0])) + "/" + "sqlite_example.db")

target_db_path = target_db
print(target_db_path)
```