# What are some specific examples of using the wrong path separator failing?

Tags: python

It's fairly common to see people recommend that you use `os.path.join()` to create file paths in Python, rather than hardcoding the path separator. In the example below, `f2` is what people generally recommend:

```
import os.path

with open('tempdir/test1.txt', 'w') as f1 :
    f1.write('Some text.')

with open(os.path.join('tempdir', 'test2.txt'), 'w') as f2:
    f2.write('Some other text')
```

However, I've had no problems just using `'/'` as a path separator on both Unix and Windows. So my question is: what are the cases when hardcoding the separator fails?

Comment: Please have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13944874/1903116) as well.