# Stripping directory and filename from path as a string

Tags: python

How can I strip the directory and filename out from a full path given to me as a string?

For example, from:

```
>>path_string
C:/Data/Python/Project/Test/file.txt
```

I want to get:

```
>>dir_and_file_string
Test/file.txt
```

I'm assuming that this is a string operation rather than a filesystem operation.

Comment: If its just string operation, just split on "/", get the last 2 elements and join them with "/" again. Or you can use `os.path.sep` as the path separator.

Comment: You should give some details on the origin of the base path, how platform independent you are, etc. It can be done through regular expressions or through something more OS-aware (e.g. how should it behave on a string like ``C:/Path/To/../Strange/../Folder``?)

Answer (score 1):

Not overly elegant, but here goes:

```
In [7]: path = "C:/Data/Python/Project/Test/file.txt"

In [8]: dir, filename = os.path.split(path)

In [9]: dir_and_file_string = os.path.join(os.path.split(dir)[1], filename)

In [10]: dir_and_file_string
Out[10]: 'Test/file.txt'
```

This is verbose, but is portable and robust.

Alternatively, you *could* treat this as a string operation:

```
In [16]: '/'.join(path.split('/')[-2:])
Out[16]: 'Test/file.txt'
```

but be sure to read [why use os.path.join over string concatenation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13944387/why-use-os-path-join-over-string-concatenation). For example, this fails if the path contains backslashes (which is the traditional path separator on Windows). Using `os.path.sep` instead of `'/'` won't solve this problem entirely.

Answer (score 1):

You should use [os.path.relpath](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.relpath)

```
import os
full_path = "/full/path/to/file"
base_path = "/full/path"
relative_path = os.path.relpath(full_path, base_path)
```

Comment: IMO for this to be a complete solution, you need to programmatically derive `base_path` from `full_path` instead of hard-coding it.

Comment: If you programatically derive ``base_path`` from ``full_path`` or viceversa, then you don't need to get the relative path because you programatically know it. I understand it as a good illustrative example. The question lacks some details.

Answer (score 0):

```
os.path.sep.join(path_string.split(os.path.sep)[-2:])
```

Comment: FYI: found in low quality queue.  It is an answer, but consider explaining a bit.

Comment: lol, my answer is not as hard to read as the one with regex :)

Comment: Surprised no one has posted a left hand side, i.e. `(dirname, fname, ext) =`

Comment: Oh, there it is. d-coder has one.  Not pretty though.

Comment: @ghostdog74 yep, regex is a bit overkill here.

Comment: Basically, its just basic string manipulation. No fancy magic.

Comment: My answer is the same as what NPE has (towards the last part). `'/'.join(path.split('/')[-2:])`, but `os.path.sep` gives you the "platform independent" path separator, supposedly.

Comment: Let's see, Linux uses '/' and winders uses '\' so the platform independent separator must be..... `|` :-)

Answer (score 0):

Little round about solution I guess but it works fine.

```
path_string = "C:/Data/Python/Project/Test/file.txt"
_,_,_,_,dir_,file1, = path_string.split("/")
dir_and_file_string = dir_+"/"+file1
print dir_and_file_string
```