# Reading multiple lines of strings into a list - Python

Tags: python, string, list

I have a code that outputs all of the files that are a .pdf in a directory. It outputs a stack of strings like below.

```
file0.PDF
file1.PDF
file2.PDF
file3.PDF
```

I want to put these strings into a list, that looks like this:

```
['file0.PDF', 'file1.PDF', 'file2.PDF', 'file3.PDF']
```

I have managed to do this with the code below.

```
import os 

list_final = []
for file in os.listdir(path):
    if ".PDF" in file:
        for value in file.split('\n'):
            list_final.append(value)
print(list_final)
```

This gives the list in the format above, which is what I want.

**Is there a better way to do this?** I feel that my code is very inefficient. I have tried through a list comprehensions such as the below but I am unsure why it does not work.

```
list_final = [value for value in file.split('\n')]
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3207219/how-do-i-list-all-files-of-a-directory

Comment: why do you need to split the filename? why are there  \n inside? are there \n inside? because .. there shouldn't

Comment: I think you could simply `list_final.append(file)` without the inner loop.

Answer (score 1):

Try using [`glob.glob()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html), it will find all files that meet a pattern:

```
import glob
print(glob.glob("*.pdf"))  # returns a list of filenames
```

Or if you want to use another path than the current path, just join it to the pattern

```
print(glob.glob(path + "/*.pdf"))  # returns a list of filenames
```

[Or even better](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13944387/why-use-os-path-join-over-string-concatenation), use [os.path.join()](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/os.path.html#os.path.join) instead:

```
from os.path import join
glob.glob(join(path, "/*.pdf"))
```

Comment: you can just do `glob.glob(path + "/*.pdf")`, or even better, use [os.path.combine](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/os.path.html#os.path.join)

Comment: now looks better, + 1

Answer (score 0):

you can use a list comprehension:

```
list_final = [e for e in os.listdir(path) if e.endswith('.PDF')]
```

or you could use [pathlib.Path.glob](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.glob) :

```
from pathlib import Path

p = Path(path)
list_final = [e.name for e in p.glob('*.PDF')]
```