# The python code needs to get the user's username to open a file on the C:/Users/USERNAME/ directory

Tags: python

I want to open a file in the desktop, or anywhere else in the C:/Users/USERNAME/ directory. but I don't know what the code to get the username is.
for example, in batch-file programming I could use:]

```
c:/Users/%USERNAME%/...
```

I want to use it in the open function. I have tried both:

```
open('C:/Users/%%USERNAME/Desktop/data3.txt')

open('C:/Users/%USERNAME%/Desktop/data3.txt')
```

I know there should be an import that can give the username to my code. But I don't know what it is. And I also would like to know if I can use the username like %USERNAME% or %%USERNAME or a single thing that doesn't need any import.

Comment: Since the desktop directory is under home directory for all systems you better get the home directory and append the desktop. Sometimes user name and home directory name may differ.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/4028943/2681662

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Three ways to do this using the `os` module:

1. Use `os.getlogin()`:

```
import os
>>> os.path.join("C:", os.sep, "Users", os.getlogin(), "Desktop")
'C:\\Users\\your_username\\Desktop'
```

2. Use `os.environ()`:

```
>>> os.path.join(os.environ['userprofile'], "Desktop")
'C:\\Users\\your_username\\Desktop'
```

3. Use `os.path.exapndvars()`:

```
>>> os.path.join(os.path.expandvars("%userprofile%"), "Desktop")
'C:\\Users\\your_username\\Desktop'
```

Comment: f-strings for python 3: `open(f'C:/Users/{os.getlogin()}/Desktop/data3.txt'')`

Comment: @It_is_Chris - It's recommended to use `os.path.join` while concatenating file paths. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13944387/why-use-os-path-join-over-string-concatenation)

Answer (score 0):

you can use `expanduser` and `~` for that :

```
import os

open(os.path.expanduser('~\\Desktop\\data3.txt'))
```

or if you want to use `os.path.join` :

```
open(os.path.join(os.path.expanduser('~'), 'Desktop', 'data3.txt'))
```