# str.replace "\" to "/"

Tags: python-2.7

My question is too simple. However I don't know the terms to use and hence may not be able to find an answer to this on stackoverflow.

I am using Python 2.7

I need to know how to convert this path,

```
E:\Documents and Settings\Admin\Desktop\new.html
```

to this path

```
E:/Documents and Settings/Admin/Desktop/new.html
```

Also, if you can please edit my subject line to something that will make others easily find this answer.

Thanks in advance and apologies if this is a repeated question.

Comment: Try http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_replace.htm

Comment: What exactly are you asking? Do you need a regex? Please explain what you are trying to do.

Comment: @MattDMo When I try to open the file using this path - E:\Documents and Settings\Admin\Desktop\new.html it says invalid path... I because it will only find the file if I use "/" instead of "\"... I am looking to convert the "\" into "/". By the way did you mark down my question?

Comment: How is this related to absolute vs. relative paths? Don't you just want to change the delimiters?

Comment: @pyStarter string replace wont replace "\"

Comment: `str.replace` [works on my machine](http://ideone.com/AqUuac).

Comment: @Kevin how are you doing it? like this? - str.replace("\","/"). It won't work, does it?

Comment: @Md.Mohsin The character "\" is a special character. String replace will surely work, if you escape it properly, e.g. "\\" or similar (have not tested the exact escaping procedure).

Comment: @pyStarter how do we escape it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The character "\" is a special character. String replace will surely work, if you escape it properly, e.g. "\".
Here is a minimum working example of what I mean:

```
inString = 'jo\jo\jo'
outString = inString.replace("\\","/")
```

will yield "jo/jo/jo" as a result in `outString`.

**Side note**
From the string given in your question I assume that you aim for transforming directory paths. You may want to consider the package `os` which is readily available for python, cf. the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html) and an [application example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13162372/using-absolute-unix-paths-in-windows-with-python).

Comment: Thanks for all your efforts pyStarter, I truly appreciate it. This is more like an answer. Better than reading just half and marking down the question just because reader alone doesn't understand it. I wonder how others interpreted it right.

Answer (score 2):

Just use a raw string literal:

```
path = r"E:\Documents and Settings\Admin\Desktop\new.html"
```

The reason Python is giving an error is because `\n` is an escape sequence for the newline character. Raw string literals are not processed for escape sequences.