# OS-agnostic relative path using pathlib

Tags: python, pathlib

I have a string variable `dirname`, that contains path with correct slashes ('/' if on Linux, '\' if on Windows).

And I have a relative filename string that may contain wrong slashes.

How do I join them and get a correct full filename for the OS, where I am running the script, using pathlib?

For example running on Linux:

```
dirname = '/users/myname/dir1'
filename1 = '..\\dir2\\file.txt'
filename2 = '../dir2/file.txt'
```

I want to join `dirname` with either `filename1` or `filename2`, and get `/users/myname/dir2/file.txt` in both cases.

Running on Windows:

```
dirname = 'C:\\dir1'
filename1 = '..\\dir2\\file.txt'
filename2 = '../dir2/file.txt'
```

I want to join `dirname` with either `filename1` or `filename2`, and get `C:\\dir2\\file.txt` in both cases.

Comment: have you tried `os.path.join` ?

Comment: @sahasrara62 With `os.path.join` I need to replace slashes for correct ones for the OS where I am running it, don't I? I want OS-independent solution.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using absolute unix paths in windows with python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13162372/using-absolute-unix-paths-in-windows-with-python)

Comment: I'm confused, how do you manage to obtain the correct `dirname` string, yet cannot tell whether you should use `filename1` or `filename2` ?

Comment: @AMC `dirname` comes as a command line argument so it is always correct with respect to OS, filenames are listed in an input file, which may come from Windows side

Answer (score 2):

A potential solution would be to store only the components of the path:

```py
import pathlib

path_1 = pathlib.Path(r"/users/myname/dir1")
print(path_1)

path_list = ["dir2", "file.txt"]

path_2 = pathlib.Path(*path_list)
print(path_2)

res = path_1.joinpath(path_2)
print(res)
```

Output:

```
/users/myname/dir1
dir2/file.txt
/users/myname/dir1/dir2/file.txt
```

Unfortunately this isn't perfect, it seems that file paths can get quite messy. See for example [cross-platform splitting of path in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4579908/cross-platform-splitting-of-path-in-python). [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31273488/11301900) is quite neat.