# Relative path with windows and Python

Tags: python, operating-system, relative-path

For my project, i have to read from some files. My colleague and i have one a Mac, one a Windows and because we do not always want to change the whole filenames, we want to insert relative paths, which turned out to not work.

The relative path we use:

```
 rel_path = "data/output/db_snapshot.log"
```

Then i imported `os` and wanted to do

```
path_db = os.path.abspath(rel_path)
```

But for output i get an error:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\mossnef\\PycharmProjects\\model_py_dms_bubble_system\\sim\\analysis\\data\\output\\db_snapshot.log'
```

If i though copy and paste the whole path into my path variable there is no problem at all and i can read it:

```
path_db = r"C:\Users\mossnef\PycharmProjects\model_py_dms_bubble_system\data\output\db_snapshot.log"
```

I already found out that for Windows the `r` i added is needed for some reason. Is there a way of using the relative path to make it work for both Windows and Mac?

Comment: Looks like you've got your python file in a sub dir.

Comment: The 'r' you add at the beginning means raw text, so the backslashes treated as part of the path instead of escape char. It is required on Win, well since win path includes \. Linux doesn't.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Platform-independent file paths?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6036129/platform-independent-file-paths)

Answer (score 0):

You have two different paths.

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\mossnef\\PycharmProjects\\model_py_dms_bubble_system\\sim\\analysis\\data\\output\\db_snapshot.log'
```

the second path does not contain

```
\\sim\\analysis
```

Please note that `os.path.abspath` uses `os.getcwd()` to derive the absolute path.

You may be using it from within the wrong folder.