# Generating file paths by adding file names onto a string

Tags: python, python-3.x

The user inputs a string signifying a folder name, then hardcoded file names are added onto that string from a list to create two absolute file paths.

The first file path is ok, but the second adds the filename onto the already added first filename.

```
files = ["file1.txt", "file2.txt"]
path = str(input("Path: "))
new_paths = []

for file in files:
    path += r"\{0}".format(file)
    new_paths.append(path)

print(new_paths)
```

Supposing an user input of:

```
C:\\Users\User\Desktop\file_folder
```

The file paths added onto the `new_paths` list are:

```
['C:\\\\Users\\Users\\Desktop\\file_folder\\file1.txt', 'C:\\\\Users\\Users\\Desktop\\file_folder\\file1.txt\\file2.txt']
```

As opposed to the desired result of:

```
['C:\\\\Users\\Users\\Desktop\\file_folder\\file1.txt', 'C:\\\\Users\\Users\\Desktop\\file_folder\\file2.txt']
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Platform-independent file paths?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6036129/platform-independent-file-paths)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are overwriting your variable `path`, try

```
files = ["file1.txt", "file2.txt"]
path = str(input("Path: "))
new_paths = []

for file in files:
    file_path = path + r"\{0}".format(file)
    new_paths.append(file_path)

print(new_paths)
```

Answer (score 1):

You are updating the same variable. Just use it:

```
for file in files:
    new_paths.append(path + r"\{0}".format(file))

print(new_paths)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do with below mentioned code -

```
[os.path.join(path, x) for x in files] 
# prints you entered path+files
```

Complete Code:

```
import argparse
files = ["file1.txt", "file2.txt"]

def create_argparse():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()

    parser.add_argument('-p','--path',
                        help='path')
    return parser.parse_args()

def main():
    args = create_argparse()
    path = args.path

    print [os.path.join(path, x) for x in files]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.exit(main())
```

***Reference:***

https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html