# How to write to a directory os agnostic?

Tags: python

I am developing on a Windows machine some code that will be run in a Linux environment. I know the path of the file in Linux will be /tmp/ that I need to write to. The accepted answer to this question does not work on Windows: [Platform-independent file paths?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6036129/platform-independent-file-paths)

when I try `open(path.join('tmp', 'fileToOpen.txt'), 'w')` I get "FileNotFoundError: [Error 2] No such file or directory: 'tmp\fileToWrite.txt'"

How can this be resolved?

Comment: You will be better off using [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) instead of `os.path`

Comment: Use `pathlib` for this. Also, doesn't `tmp` not exist on windows? You can try using the `tempfile` module.

Comment: @jakub It doesn't exist but I created a C:\tmp\  for testing purposes.

Answer (score 2):

As @Tomerikoo and @jakub pointed out, you want to use the [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) and [`tempfile`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tempfile.html) modules in Python:

- [`tempfile.gettempdir()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tempfile.html#tempfile.gettempdir) will retrieve the location and
- [`pathlib.PurePath`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pure-paths) will join the filename to that path in an OS agnostic fashion.

You'll end up with something like:

```
open(PurePath(gettempdir(), 'fileToOpen.txt'), 'w')
```

Comment: When I use `tempfile.gettempdir()` it returns C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Temp. I have created a file at C:\tmp\ for my development though.

Comment: Then you have not configured your OS to use that as the file for temporary directories. You can't really both want the OS to decide and yourself to have a say.

Comment: @tripleee I want to be able to write to the directory C:\tmp\ irrespective of OS. I realize there is some OS elements at play with defining the temp directory but is there not just an agnostic way to write to the directory going around that?

Comment: Semi-agnostically put the directory name in an environment variable and use `os.environ["TMPDIR"]` or whatever. (This is a standard system variable on U*x systems, but no idea about Windows ... thank heavens).

Comment: Why though @Michael?  Why not just use the *correct* temp storage location for the OS?

Comment: @mikebabcock Let's say I don't want to write to temp though. Say I know there will be a directory called \thisdir\ on Windows and Linux machines and I want to write to it agnostically. How can that be done?